# How to find the how many TRUE or FALSE are in the VALUE column

Tags: python, pyspark, boolean, numeric

I have a PySpark Dataframe with a column of strings. I did find if those columns are numeric or not. But now I want to find how many TRUE are in the Value column.

```
values = [('25q36',),('75647',),('13864',),('8758K',),('07645',)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['ID',])
df.show()
+-----+
|   ID|
+-----+
|25q36|
|75647|
|13864|
|8758K|
|07645|
+-----+
```

I did apply the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

my_df.select(
  "ID",
  F.col("ID").cast("int").isNotNull().alias("Value ")
).show()

+-----+------+
|   ID|Value |
+-----+------+
|25q36| false|
|75647|  true|
|13864|  true|
|8758K| false|
|07645|  true|
+-----+------+
```

But now I want to know how many TRUE or False are in that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Night.

Try something like that...

```
df.groupBy('Value').count().show()
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job done!

```
df['Value'].value_counts()
```